# Alter outer argument var of node.js

Tags: node.js

Please look at these 3 code blocks first.

**Code Block 1:**

```
var t1 = function(aaa) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        a = 'bb';
        aaa.push(a);
    }, 1000);

}

var t3 = function() {
    var aa = new Array;
    aa[0] = 'aa';

    console.log(aa);
    t1(aa);

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(aa);
    }, 3000);
}

t3();
```

**Output:**
[ 'aa' ]
[ 'aa', 'bb' ]

---

**Code Block 2:**

```
var t1 = function(aaa) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        aaa[1] = 'bb';
    }, 1000);

}

var t3 = function() {
    var aa = new Array;
    aa[0] = 'aa';

    console.log(aa);
    t1(aa);

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(aa);
    }, 3000);
}

t3();
```

**Output:**
[ 'aa' ]
[ 'aa', 'bb' ]

---

**Code Block 3:**

```
var t1 = function(aaa) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        aaa = aaa.concat('bb');
    }, 1000);

}

var t3 = function() {
    var aa = new Array;
    aa[0] = 'aa';

    console.log(aa);
    t1(aa);

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(aa);
    }, 3000);
}

t3();
```

**Output:**
[ 'aa' ]
[ 'aa' ]

---

The problem is code block 3 that the 'concat' method can't modify the 'aaa' var pass by argument.
What's the difference of 'concat' ,'push' and direct modify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In codeblock 1 and 2, you are modifying the contents of `aa`.

While in codeblock 3 you are **rebinding** `aaa` to another array, and the `aaa` in function `t1` is not a reference to the outside `aa` anymore. So the outside `aa` is not being modified.

you can refer to [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) to see the detailed explanation on Javascript's variable passing behavior.